# Log created by custom watcher by "indexing action" , not visible in kibana observability log/stream

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-watcher

I have made a custom watcher with indexing action.
For this i created a index `watcher-index` using

```
PUT /watcher-index
{
  settings:{
    number_of_shards:3,
    number_of_replicas:1
  },
  "mappings":{
    "_default_":{
      "@timestamp":{
        "enabled":true,
        "store":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I mentioned in particular that @timestamp should be a default field. Now I mentioned the same in watcher definition -

```
{
  "actions":{
    "index":{
      "index":"watcher-index"
    }
  }
}
```

Action runs successfully and document is created as I can see by `GET /watcher-index/_search`. However, it does not display in kibana observability log/stream. A `GET /watcher-index/_search{"query":{"match":{"field":"@timestamp"}}}` returns 0 `hits:[]`. How can I solve this issue? I am using version-8.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for field name `field` and the value `@timestamp`.

Check with the following.

```
GET /watcher-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "@timestamp"
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to see your data in the observability section the index name needs to start with the following parameters.

```
logs-*,filebeat-*,kibana_sample_data_logs*
```

You can update it with the observability settings.

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply. I changed the GET query but still no hits. I guess @timestamp is not created. Also I changed the observability settings but still logs from _index:watcher-index are not visible.

Comment: can you share the result of GET /watcher-index/_search